# Why is this website still in Beta?

Tags: discussion

After 4+ years and 2,500+ questions?

Is this website really still considered being a beta?

Comment: [Good News](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta?cb=1)! (Sorta...) All sites like WW that were _7_ years old have _sorta_ graduated out of Beta. Maybe, just maybe, in another 2 years we'll hit that target, too.

Answer (score 4):

Site statistics as of this date indicate that we have:

- 1.2 questions per day, which is very small for a Stackexchange website
- 93% of questions answered which is excellent
- 194 avid users and 6075 total users which is considered a sound supportable site.
- 2.2 answers per question which is good, but below the excellent threshold of 2.5 answers per question
- 3918 visits per day which is also considered excellent.

The site has been stable throughout its life and, as I interpret StackExchange policy, successful.  The only major difference between a Beta site and a graduated site I have found is that moderators are selected by StackExchange instead of community elections.  I was recently selected as a moderator, I suspect partially because I volunteered myself, to give something back to the site I had enjoyed and learned from for years, when StackExchange asked for nominations (I was also the sole candidate at that time).  Moderator duties are very light and the community members mostly manage things without the need for interventions.

I am not aware of any other significant differences other that the word "Beta" in the site title.  Other respondents may have noticed other differences (?)

Comment: Another major difference is the Rep requirements for privileges. They get a big bump after graduation.

Comment: they also give you fancy graphics, not the standard basic stuff.

Comment: @bowlturner The design backlog is...backlogged. I'm not sure custom graphics are part of graduating anymore.